# Give read/write access to an S3 bucket to a specific Cognito user group

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I have users in a Cognito user pool, some of whom are in an `Administrators` group. These administrators need to be allowed to read/write to a specific S3 bucket, and other users must not.

To achieve this, I assigned a role to the `Administrators` group which looked like this:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket-name/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Then in my Angular app, I sign in and use Amplify's `Storage` class to do the following:

```
Storage.put("test.txt", "hello")
    .then(result => ...)
    .catch(err => ...);
```

The `Amplify.configure` in this case is:

```
const amplifyConfig = {
  Auth: {
    region: "eu-west-2",
    userPoolId: xxx,
    userPoolWebClientId: yyy,
    mandatorySignIn: false,
  },
  Storage: {
    AWSS3: {
      bucket: 'my-bucket-name',
      region: "eu-west-2"
    }
  }
};
Amplify.configure(amplifyConfig);
```

The problem here was that, internally, no credentials were provided to the `Storage.put` call, and the task fails as follows:

```
[DEBUG] 31:08.487 Credentials - Failed to load credentials 
ZoneAwarePromise {__zone_symbol__state: false, __zone_symbol__value: NotAuthorizedException: 
Unauthenticated access is not supported for this identity pool.
```

Reading around, this seemed to be because you don't get credentials *at all* unless you have a federated identity pool. So I created an identity pool attached to my user pool + app client, with all the defaults, and added its ID to my `Amplify.configure` config.

This still doesn't work, but this time I **do** get credentials - and they are for the IAM role specified in the identity pool's **Authenticated Role**.

So now if I add the above S3 permissions to that role, all my code works, but there's a massive security hole in that now *all* users (not just admins) can read/write the admin's bucket. Ah.

**So, how can I get credentials for the role specified in the admin user group's settings if and only if I'm an admin?**

**Or alternatively, can this be solved by some clever setting in the federated identity whereby it assigns the correct roles there based on the user's group?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution lies in the federated identity pool's settings.

By default the identity pool will provide the IAM role that it's configured with. In other words, one of either the "unauthenticated role" or the "authenticated role" that it's set up with.

But it can be told instead to provide a role specified by the authentication provider. That's what will solve the problem here.

1. In the AWS console, in Cognito, open the relevant identity pool.
2. Click "Edit identity pool" (top right)
3. Expand "Authentication Providers"
4. Under Authenticated Role Selection, choose "Choose role from token".

That will allow Cognito to specify its own roles, and you will find that the users get the privileges of their group.